# Problem with updating the hashmap

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, hashmap

Good day!

I am making a shopping cart and I've decided to store it temporarily in hashmap (session) before the customer checks-out. My problem is I am having difficulty on updating the no. of items inside the quantity text box.

My code is as follows:

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="cart" items="${cartList}">
     <form method="POST" action="ShoppingCartUpdate">
            ${cart.value.productId}
            ${cart.value.productName}
            ${cart.value.price}
            <input type="text" value="${cart.value.quantity}"name="quantity">
            <input type="submit" value ="Update" name="Update">
     </form>
 </c:forEach>
```

My servlet:

```
 int productId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productId"));//ERROR HERE.. 
 int quantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));

 Cart item = (Cart)cartList.get(productId);
 item.setQuantity(quantity);
 double price = item.getPrice();
 subtotal = price * quantity;

 cartList.put(productId, item);
```

Even if i entered another number in the quantity field, it never updates. Hot can I correct it. Thank you.

EDIT: Error is as follows:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[ShoppingCart]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ShoppingCart threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting `productId` as request parameter, but you aren't passing it in the form at all. It arrives as `null` and this is not parseable as an integer and hence the `NumberFormatException: null`.

Add the following to the same form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="${cart.value.productId}" />
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem,

```
cartList.put(productId, item);
```

This line is unnecessary, remove it. It's Java, not PHP or something. The `item` is already in the map. You haven't removed it from the map. All changes will just be reflected in the `item` reference in the map since it refers to the same object.